# How to add library in Gradle from Maven Central?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an empty Android project, and I want to add some library to it.
For example, `Picasso`.

So I've edited 'app/build.gradle' and added follow line to the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}
```

Then I rebuilt my project. So now I want to use it, but Picasso classes is unavailable for Android Studio.

What did I miss?

Comment: That should work. Though keep in mind you have to click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button after changing build files. What version of Android Studio is this?

Comment: @ScottBarta the latest for now, 0.4.4.

Comment: @ScottBarta thanks, I've missed exactly this button. Thought that rebuild procedure should do this.

Comment: Okay, adding as an answer. In newer versions (forget if it's in 0.4.6 or is going out in 0.4.7) we put a reminder at the top of the editor window if you've made changes and need to sync the file. Obviously it would be better to have it automatically sync if it knows it's needed, but for various reasons that's hard and it's something we'll do later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing the build.gradle file by hand, you need to click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button before the IDE will pick up new dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

In Top build.gradle (Project: YourProject) I added:

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.187'
         //NOTE: you can get the latest version in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2

         } 
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

> NOTE: I added this along with the predefined jcenter() repositories.

And then for my app/build.gradle file I added whichever library or dependency I needed on:

```
dependencies {
....//Add dependency here
}
```

I hope this can help!